# Which event occur first while using MailParser Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, email-parsing

I am using [MailParser](https://github.com/andris9/mailparser) for parsing emails in node js. In following events in mailparser which one works first or it works parallel

```
mp.on("attachment", function(attachment, mail){

});

mp.on('end', function(mail) {

});
```

Comment: End is called when the parse is end so I suppose any other event is before it.

Answer (score 0):

```
mp.on('end', function(mail) {
    //more code here
});
```

its work first its better you to make attachments inside this function